# Characteristic function of ito process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, characteristic-functions

I'm given process $X(t) = \int_{0}^{t} a(s)dB(s) $ where a(s) is a square-integrable deterministic function

I need to show, that $E[e^{imX(t)}] = e^{-\frac{m^2}{2}\int_{0}^{t}a^2(s)ds}$

---

My attempt:

I write $e^{imX(t)}$ as an Ito process:

$f(x,t) = e^{imx}$, $f_{x} = ime^{imx}, f_{t} = 0, f_{xx} = -m^2e^{imx}, dx = a(t)dB(t), [dx*dx] = a^2(t)dt$

So $d(f(x,t)) = d(e^{imx}) = i*m*f*a(t)dB(t)-\frac{1}{2}f*m^2*a^2(t)dt$

So $e^{imx} = 1 + \int_{0}^{t}i*m*e^{imx(s)}*a(s)dB(s)-\int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{2}e^{imx(s)}*m^2*a^2(s)ds$

And now I'm lost. When I take expectation of both sides even though I get rid of the stochastic integral, I still have something on the right which I don't know how to deal with ... I'd appreciate if anyone could give a helping hand.

Comment: Please be careful to distinguish $x$ and $x(t)$; for instance in your last equation it should read $e^{imx(t)}$ on the left-hand side.

Comment: Yeah, this was a slip up, meant to distinguish, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the stochastic integral

$$M_t := i \int_0^t m e^{im X_s} a_s \, dB_s$$

is a martingale, it has, in particular, constant expectation and so $\mathbb{E}(M_t) = \mathbb{E}(M_0)=0$. Taking the expectation in the last equation in your question, we therefore get

$$\mathbb{E}(e^{im X_t}) =1+ 0 - \frac{m^2}{2} \int_0^t \mathbb{E}(e^{im X_s}) a(s)^2 \, ds.$$

This shows that the mapping

$$\varphi(t) := \mathbb{E}(e^{im X_t})$$

satisfies the ordinary differential equation

$$\frac{d}{dt} \varphi(t) = - \frac{m^2}{2} a(t)^2 \varphi(t), \qquad \varphi(0)=1.$$

Find the solution to this equation in order to prove the assertion...

Comment: Thank you very much. Sigh, can’t believe I did not get this myself. Anyway, shouldn’t smth like fubini-tonelli be mentioned regarding expectation and integral?

Comment: @Makina Yes, we need Fubini to interchange the expectation and the (Riemann) integral.

Comment: Another possible solution which is maybe al little more straitforward is to use the fact, X is a Wiener integral and as such it is gaussian, moreover the value of the expnential of a guassian variable is the exponential of its mean (here equal to 0) plusone half its variance i.e. $i^2m^2.\int_{0}^{t}a^2(s)ds$ ( using tô's Ismoetry) and you get the result unless mistaken. Regards

Comment: @TheBridge Yes, that's correct ... typically when I mention this, the OP tells me that (s)he is supposed to *prove* that $\int_0^t a(s) \, dB_s$ is Gaussian, and therefore I'm a bit tired of mentioning it at all.

Comment: I had to prove it this way, otherwise why would I make this post. The direct way is trivial. Have to go the cancer way ..

Comment: Just one remark. When we interchanged the expectation and the Riemann integral, does the $a(s)^2$ get out of it due to being deterministic?

Comment: @Makina yes, exactly. Note that the assertion is wrong if $a$ is not deterministic.

Comment: Ye that what I was thinking. But what exactly does deterministic aspect entail? Does it basically make it a constant in this case? I mean, I know that a non-deterministic would be a function of Wiener process.

Comment: @Makina What do you mean by "was does it entail"? You can choose any (square-integrable) function $a$ which depends only on time $s$ and not on $\omega$, e.g. $a(s) = \exp(s)$ or $a(s)=s^k$ or.... these mappings are hardly constant.

Comment: The question I tried to ask was how do I get it out of the expectation of the product as shown in the solution. Why does it remain the same and is treated like a constant in this case

Comment: @Makina That's simply the linearity of the expectation. If $s$ is fixed, then $a(s)^2$ is a constant and therefore $\mathbb{E}(a(s)^2 Y) =a(s)^2 \mathbb{E}(Y)$ for any integrable random variable $Y$.